# Firebase Auth throwing "auth/internal-error" when trying to use PhoneAuthProvider method in Ionic React IOS mobile application

Tags: ios, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication, ionic-react

I am currently having some issues trying to integrate Google Firebase authentication into a React Ionic mobile application. So far I have been able to set up the app to run correctly on both web and android but am running into repeated issues with IOS. The code runs correctly for [Firebase auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.auth.Auth) login on android does not seem to be running on IOS.

The initial call to "signInWithEmailAndPassword" seems to work fine and returns "auth/multi-factor-auth-required" but any time I try to make a call to "[verifyPhoneNumber](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider#verifyphonenumber)" on ios I will receive the response of "Firebase: An internal AuthError has occurred. (auth/internal-error)", there are no further details provided in any part of the error returned.

```
//Firebase setup in seperate file with code like these 2 lines 
app.initializeApp(config);
const firebaseAuth = app.auth();
//

firebaseAuth
.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
.then(function (user) {
        //other code
})
.catch(function (error) {
        if (error.code === "auth/multi-factor-auth-required") {
            let resolver = error.resolver;
            setTimeout(() => {
                phoneAuth(appVerifier, resolver);
            }, 2000);
      } else {
          //other code
      }
});

//following code is part of the method phoneAuth() above
var phoneInfoOptions = {
    var phoneInfoOptions = {
      multiFactorHint: resolver.hints[0],
      session: resolver.session,
    };
    var phoneAuthProvider = new firebase.PhoneAuthProvider();
    phoneAuthProvider
      .verifyPhoneNumber(phoneInfoOptions, appVerifier)
      .then(function (verificationId) {
        console.log("verify Id recieved");
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
```

Things I have checked/tried so far are:
followed all steps in [firebase docs](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/ios/mfa)
Setup ios app in firebase console and followed the [steps listed](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#:%7E:text=Go%20to%20the%20Firebase%20console,in%20the%20bundle%20ID%20field.)

Has anyone run into issues like this previously and has any advice on what I could check next?

Thanks

Comment: Hi @Jordan, Have you or anyone managed to solve this?

Comment: Hi did you find a way to solve it ?

Comment: Same here. Any news about it? Thanks.

Comment: Same problem here too when I use signInWithEmailAndPassword everything works fine but then when I use phoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber() I'm getting 'internal-error'. For me it's link with some APNs silent notification that is not working properly but don't find any solution yet

Comment: Hello,
I am facing the same, does anyone manage to resolve it? Or found any alternative of it?
Any help would be appreciated.